# how to distribute appointed numbers for specific times in PHP

Tags: php

For example, I have 1,2,3.

And what i want is, give number 2 and 3 to 1, give 1 and 3 to 2, give 1 and 2 to 3

so each number is distributed only twice and each number has only two different numbers.

Just like this

> `1=>[2,3]; 2=>[1,3]; 3=>[1,2].`

And then, when i have 1,2,3,4

> `1=>[2,3]; 2=>[1,3]; 3=>[1,2]; 4=>[nothing because can't give 4 to itself]. is not what i want.`
>
> `1=>[2,3]; 2=>[3,4]; 3=>[1,4]; 4=>[1,2]. is one result that i want.`

If i wanna use PHP to achieve this, what should i do?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess write some code.

Comment: I guess the homework question is about thinking of an algorithm

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I try something for fulfil your requirements,

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4);
        $count = count($array);
        $res = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if ($count-1 < $key+1) {
                $key = -1;
                echo $value."=>".$array[$key+1].", ".$array[$key+2].'; <br>';
                $res[$value] = array($array[$key+1],$array[$key+2]);
            } elseif ($count-1 < $key+2) {
                $key1 = 0;
                echo $value."=>".$array[$key+1].", ".$array[$key1].'; <br>';
                $res[$value] = array($array[$key+1],$array[$key1]);
            } else {
                echo $value."=>".$array[$key+1].", ".$array[$key+2].'; <br>';
                $res[$value] = array($array[$key+1],$array[$key+2]);
            }
        }
        var_dump($res);
```